# Calling function from an onlyOwner smart contract

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin, foundry, forge

I have two separate contract files. One is the source contract to test and the other is a foundry test contract.

**Source Contract**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity 0.8.13;

contract Helloworld is
    Initializable,
    ERC721Upgradeable,
    UUPSUpgradeable,
    OwnableUpgradeable,
    MulticallUpgradeable
{
  uint256 public idCounter;
  function setCounter(uint256 counter_) public onlyOwner {
        require(counter_ != 0, "Counter cannot be 0");
        counter = counter_;
    }
   function counterCheck() external payable {
        require(msg.value == counter, "Invalid counter");

        unchecked {
            idCounter++;
        }

        _safeMint(msg.sender, idCounter, "");
    }

}
```

I also have the below foundry test case in the below test contract when I am receiving `[FAIL. Reason: revert: Ownable: caller is not the owner]` error.

I tried inheriting the source contract as in the below code.

Requirement: Become the contract owner or run the test without the owner error.

NB: The overflow issue in the code is known. The foundry test case is planned to address it.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.13;


import "./sourcecontract.sol";
import "forge-std/Test.sol";

contract chilcontract is Helloworld{
  Helloworld public hw;
  }

contract countertest is Test{
  childcontract childInstance;
  
  function setUp() public{
    childInstance = new childcontract();
    }

  function testcounter() public{

    //set counter
    uint256 counter = 1 ether;// counter set to 1 ether
    childInstance.counterCheck(counter);
    console.log("Counter set");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You used `OwnableUpgradeable` contract. It needs to be used with a proxy.

Upgradeable contracts don't use constructor because the storage is on the proxy and not on the implementation contract.

So, the `OwnableUpgradeable` does not set the msg.sender the default owner. To do so, you should call the initialize function.

I recommend you to read this: https://docs.openzeppelin.com/upgrades-plugins/1.x/writing-upgradeable

Comment: I added `function initialize() public initializer {
        __Ownable_init();
    }` above the setup function, however while running the forge test, produced the same error. I couldn't find a foundry test case based on this logic.